# WINDOW_TYPE_ALERT service view, on back button listener

Tags: android

I have a service which displays a floating view on the window manager (using WINDOW_TYPE_ALERT permission)

What I want to do, is to dismiss this view when the back button is pressed.
So is there any work around to listen to the back button while my service's view is visible?

Comment: short question, you already tried the `onKeyDown` method?

Comment: onKeyDown is not available in Service class

Comment: Have a look at `dispatchKeyEvent()`

Comment: in which class does it exist?
BTW, this app just does it when it is visible
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.schiztech.swapps&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zY2hpenRlY2guc3dhcHBzIl0.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the best work around I've come across.
When I add my Service's view to WindowManager I also add a popup window with the following properties

```
setFocusable(true);
setOnDismissListener(instanceOfMyService);
setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
setOutsideTouchable(false);
setTouchable(false);
setWidth(0);
setHeight(0);
```

this way the onDismiss method will be only called when the back button pressed (that what I can see til now)
then I can handle this call back.
Thanks